# Replace values in a vector in R

Tags: r, list, replace, formulas, outliers

all.

I need to replace a specific value (an outlier) in a vector in R by the vector mean (one other suggestion in this case would be appreciated). I would like to use the R-function "replace" to do so, but I´m still a beginner and I´m getting an error I can´t fix by myself. This is what I´m trying:

```
replace(data$students, outlier, mean(data&students))
```

Someone told me in another post that I can`t use & for formulas, so perhaps that´s the problem, but at the same time this is the error I´m getting:

```
 invalid subscriptor type 'list'
```

This means I must create a list before typing the replace function? what should I type?

Sorry for the basic information, but I just started with R. Thanks a lot for your nice responses.

Comment: You have used `data&` instead of `data$`.  Also the secnd argument in `replace` should be logical or numeric index,.  It is not clear what the `outlier` is

Comment: The & was a typo. I did it correctly in my code :-). The problem may be in the outlier. I have     outlier <- dplyr::filter(data,data$students > 2000) and it returns a vector with numbers and strings.... a list?

Comment: regarding the `outlier`, it should be an element identifier.  i.e. as an example to replace NA `i1 <- which(is.na(data$students)); replace(data$students, i1, mean(data$students, na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: Thanks for your response, akrun. Could you please tell how to  convert my ourtlier    dplyr::filter(data,data$students > 2000) into an element identifier?

Comment: Please check if the posted answer fits to your criteria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the outlier detection is based on values greater than 2000, then

```
data$students <- with(data, replace(students, students > 2000, mean(students)))
```

Regarding the `mean` part, it is not clear whether the `mean` takes the outlier values too.  If it is not

```
i1 <- data$students >2000
data$students <- with(data, replace(students, i1, mean(students[i1])))
```

Comment: Thank you!! In a first approach, it seems that it doesn´t, so apparently the first option works :-)